# Using Multi-byte Character for function and sorts name in Z3py

Tags: python, z3py

It may be an unfamiliar question for English speaker.

Python3 accepts multi-byte characters as the name of variables.
However, in the following z3py example, Human -> 人間 (Japanese) causes error.
My original Python3 can handle multi-byte characters without any problems.

```
from z3 import *

Object = DeclareSort('Object')

人間 = Function('人間', Object, BoolSort())
Mortal = Function('Mortal', Object, BoolSort())

# a well known philosopher 
soc= Const('socrates', Object)

# free variables used in forall must be declared Const in python
x = Const('x', Object)

axioms = [ForAll([x], Implies(人間(x), Mortal(x))), 
          人間(socrates)]

s = Solver()
s.add(axioms)

print(s.check()) # prints sat so axioms are coherent

# classical refutation
s.add(Not(Mortal(socrates)))

print(s.check()) # prints unsat so soc is Mortal
```

Error says _to_ascii() goes something wrong. Do you have any idea what happened here and let me know if I can use multibyte characters with minor rewriting the z3 main script or not. I saw some cases in Internet that z3py with Japanese can work. So, it is possible..., I think.

```
usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/z3/z3core.py in Z3_mk_string_symbol(a0, a1, _elems)
   1526 
   1527 def Z3_mk_string_symbol(a0, a1, _elems=Elementaries(_lib.Z3_mk_string_symbol)):
-> 1528   r = _elems.f(a0, _to_ascii(a1))
   1529   _elems.Check(a0)
   1530   return r

ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the `_to_ascii()` method that your traceback is referencing, which contains this code (from latest [Z3Prover/z3 release, z3-4.8.7](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases)):

*z3/z3core.py @ 69*

```
def _to_ascii(s):
  if isinstance(s, str):
    try:
      return s.encode('ascii')
    except:
      # kick the bucket down the road.  :-J
      return s
  else:
    return s
```

You'll notice in the `try` that it does an `ascii` encoding on `s` (where `s` is the function name you pass to the `Function` constructor), which fits with the method name. Obviously, your given name "人間" cannot be encoded as ASCII, so the encoding here fails. Eventually this bubbles up, causing the `ArgumentError` you're seeing.

Looking at the code, I suspect that whatever sources you saw saying that z3 supported Japanese names were incorrect. You could try submitting a bug on the z3 GitHub about the failure, but seeing as the method is called `_to_ascii()`, I don't see it gaining much attention (maybe a Feature Request?).

That being said, you can modify the code here to allow your Japanese function name:

```
def _to_ascii(s):
  if isinstance(s, str):
    try:
      return s.encode('utf-8') # <- Note the change in encoding here
    except:
      # kick the bucket down the road.  :-J
      return s
  else:
    return s
```

Doing this, I was able to run your code (*after* renaming your `socrates` variable to `soc` :) )